# Error connecting Celery to Redis when using Docker

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, celery

I have used `docker-compose` to create a docker instance that contains redis and celery. This will build successfully, however, in my python script when I try add something to my queue i get the following error:

```
Error 8 connecting to redis:6379. nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
```

I have tried changing my the celeryconfig file addresses, and have experimented with a solution suggested here: https://github.com/mozilla-services/cliquet/issues/664 but I have not been able to fix it.

Has anyone else encountered an issue like this?

** a part of example.py **

```
app = Celery('server', broker='redis://redis:6379/0')
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)

@app.task(trail=True)
def count_words_at_url(url):
    time.sleep(50)
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return len(resp.text.split())
```

**celeryconfig.py**

```
result_backend = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
broker_url = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
worker_concurrency  =1
```

**Dockerfile.celery**

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ulimit -n 1024
CMD celery -A celeryExample worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  celery: 
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.celery
    links: 
      - redis:redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes: 
        - .:/usr/src/app
```

With the accepted answer (still need to split broker and backend to separate queues), I have managed to get everything to work as should be with the following changes :

**example.py**:

```
broker_url = os.environ.get('broker_url', 'redis://localhost:6379'),
result_backend = os.environ.get('result_backend', 'redis://localhost:6379')

app = Celery('server', broker = broker_url,
                       backend = result_backend)
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)

@app.task(trail=True)
def count_words_at_url(url):
    time.sleep(50)
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return len(resp.text.split())
```

**Dockerfile.celery**

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ENV CELERY_BROKER_URL redis://redis:6379/0
ENV CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND redis://redis:6379/0
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD celery -A celeryExample worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info
```

**celeryconfig.py**

```
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
worker_concurrency  =1
```

Comment: Celery v4.0 onwards uses lowercase configuration names. You can find the new names here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html

Comment: thanks you, I've made the changes to my config file. Sadly, I am still getting the error

Comment: Could it be that the name `redis` simply does not resolve (DNS)?

Comment: I am not a Docker compose expert... Could you remove the links part from your Docker compose script and try again? Aaaah, I see now what is the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your client (application that tries to send some task to your Celery cluster) is using the same `celeryconfig` module your Celery worker(s) running inside Docker use.

Why is this a problem? - Because everything outside your Docker infrastructure cannot resolve `redis`. Sure, if your client application (producer) runs on any docker container specified in the docker-compose script you pasted above, it will work, but if you try to run something from the host machine for an example, it will fail.

In order to make it work, you need to grab the IP of the container running redis, and use modified celeryconfig which uses this IP address.

You may even omit the step I mentioned above, and just simply use `localhost:6379` on the host machine in both broker and result_backend URLs. I also recommend you use different Redis databases for these two (say you use `6` for broker, and `8` for result_backend).

In your *example.py*, if you replace `redis://redis:6379/0` with `redis://localhost:6379/0` it should work.

So to summarise:

- All Celery workers that run *within your Docker infrastructure* should have celeryconfig that have `redis://redis:6379/1` (for an example) as broker URL, and `redis://redis:6379/3` as result backend URL.
- Every producer (a script you may want to run on your host machine for an example) that runs *outside your Docker infrastructure* should have a different celeryconfig, which configures Celery application to use `redis://localhost:6379/1` as broker, and `redis://localhost:6379/3` as result backend.

Comment: thank you! I have replaced all the ```redis:6379``` bits with ```localhost:6379```. However, I also needed to change the final line of the Dockerfile to: CMD celery -A celeryExample worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info --broker=redis://redis:6379/0 , i think this allowed redis and celery to connect - this has now removed my original error! But, now when I have submitted a job, celery intermittently loses connection to Redis, saying: ```Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Address not available.```

Comment: I advise you not to pass the broker like that to the worker. It should pick the broker URL from the celeryconfig...

Comment: In celeryconfig I know have ```broker_url = ['redis://redis:6379/0', 'redis://localhost:6379/0']``` and ```result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'```. The broker is now only being passed this way.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct. Thank you. My new connection problem still persists, if you have any thoughts on that at any point I would be very grateful.

Comment: Look at what I wrote in the summary.

Comment: you're a godsend